# Microsoft Azure Service Bus - 40400: Endpoint not found

Tags: .net, windows, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have an Azure Service Bus topic that I am able to send and retrieve to locally however when testing in our VM environment the above error occurs. Has anyone experienced this issue?

**Sample code of message consumption:**

```
        try
        {
            while (!stopFlag)
            {
                BrokeredMessage msg = null;
                try
                {
                    msg = client.Receive();
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (msg == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                try
                {
                    Handler.handleMessage(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("Spently.Listener",
                        Handler.Name + " ERROR " + x.Message + " " + x.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                client.Close();
                client = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you confirm both environment point to the same namespace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sean. Yes both are pointing to the same namespace, the main changes that have occurred with the solution are:

- Azure nuget package update to 4.13
- moved from ACS to SAS auth policy

Comment: Don't think that would be an issue. Are you getting 40400 for a specific entity or the namespace? Can you share a simple repro code anywhere?

Comment: I am getting an error for a set of topics we have for a listener service we run. I don't believe there are any issues with the namespace as we have another set of topics that are functioning properly in the same namespace. I will work on getting some sample code to share. Thank you again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an issue with nuget managing our packages. There was a version mismatch with our service projects.